# Resolving the Conflict of definitions in same namespaces

Tags: c#

I have 2 same named classes defined in 2 different namespaces and I want to include both the namespaces as using statement in my c# file, Like below:

```
using A.B;
using C.B;
```

Lets say both `A.B` and `C.B` has definition for `class foo` and one of them is to be used based on a check like below:

```
if(check)
{
   // Use A.B ones class foo
}
else
{
   // Use C.B ones class foo
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

P.S. I can't change the name of the classes.

Comment: You can use full qualified class name with namespace, e.g. `var foo = new A.B.Foo();`

Comment: Or even better: Rename one of the classes to avoid confusion in the future too.

Comment: @Jabberwocky OP mentioned that _I can't change the name of the classes._

Answer (score 4):

There is option to create alias for a namespace or a type. This is called a [using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive):

```
using ABFoo = A.B.Foo;
using CBFoo = C.B.Foo;

if (check)
{
    ABFoo foo = new ABFoo(); // Use A.B ones class foo
}
else
{
    CBFoo foo = new CBFoo(); // Use C.B ones class foo
}
```

or use fully qualified class name:

```
if (check)
{
    A.B.Foo foo = new A.B.Foo(); // Use A.B ones class foo
}
else
{
    C.B.Foo foo = new C.B.Foo(); // Use C.B ones class foo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use fully qualified class name with namespace

```cs
if (check)
{
    var foo = new A.B.Foo();
}
else
{
    var foo = new C.B.Foo();
}
```

Comment: @sporty_1993 Does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you have a class Foo in NameSpaceA

```
namespace NameSpaceA
{
    class Foo
    {
        public string Sample { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and you have also class Foo in NameSpaceB

```
namespace NameSpaceA
{
    class Foo
    {
        public string Sample { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this class in main method like this

```
using AFoo = NameSpaceA.Foo;
using BFoo = NameSpaceB.Foo;
if(check)
{
   AFoo afo = new AFoo();
}
else
{
   BFoo bFoo = new BFoo();
}
```

It is called aliasing [Aliasing](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/type-and-namespace-aliasing-csharp)

You can also use this way. It is called fully qualified name [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-namespaces/)

```
if(check)
{
   NameSpaceA.Foo afo = new NameSpaceA.Foo();
}
else
{
   NameSpaceB.Foo bFoo = new NameSpaceB.Foo();
}
```

If this helps you please select this as a correct answer. It will help the community.